# Método estático com objeto como parâmetro

Tags: java, parâmetros, objetos, método, instanciar-objeto

Estou criando um sistema bem simples para cadastro de alunos. Fiz um classe `Aluno` da seguinte forma:

```
public class Aluno {
    private String nome;
    private String matricula;
    private String curso;
    private int periodo;
    private String[] disciplinasMatriculadas;
    private int idade;
    private String endereco;

    public Aluno(String nome, String matricula, String curso, int periodo,
            int quantidadeDisciplinasPermitidas) {
        super();
        this.nome = nome;
        this.matricula = matricula;
        this.curso = curso;
        this.periodo = periodo;
        disciplinasMatriculadas = new String[quantidadeDisciplinasPermitidas];
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getMatricula() {
        return matricula;
    }

    public void setMatricula(String matricula) {
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }

    public String getCurso() {
        return curso;
    }

    public void setCurso(String curso) {
        this.curso = curso;
    }

    public int getPeriodo() {
        return periodo;
    }

    public void setPeriodo(int periodo) {
        this.periodo = periodo;
    }


    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    int d = 0;
    public String fazMatricula(String disciplina){
        if(d == disciplinasMatriculadas.length - 1){
            return "Quantidade de disciplinas excedida. O limite de matriculas para esse aluno é de " +
        disciplinasMatriculadas.length + " disciplina(s). Se desejar, cancele sua matricula em uma das disciplinas" +
                    " e faça uma nova matricula.";
        } else if(disciplinasMatriculadas.length == 0){
            return "Este aluno não pode ser matriculado em nenhuma disciplina. Por favor, fale com a secretaria.";
        } else{
            disciplinasMatriculadas[d] = disciplina;
            d++;
            return "Matricula na disciplina \"" + disciplina + "\" realizada com sucesso!";
        }
    }

    public String cancelaMatricula(String disciplina){
        boolean disciplinaMatriculada = false;
        int j = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < disciplinasMatriculadas.length - 1; i++){
            if(disciplinasMatriculadas[i].equals(disciplina)){
                disciplinaMatriculada = true;
                continue;
            }else if(i == disciplinasMatriculadas.length - 1 && disciplinaMatriculada == false){
                System.out.println("Aluno não está matriculado na disciplina \"" + disciplina + 
                        "\", portanto não é possivel cancelar essa matricula"); 
                break;
            }else{
                disciplinasMatriculadas[j] = disciplinasMatriculadas[i];
                j++;
            }
        }return "Cancelamento da matricula na disciplina \"" + disciplina + "\" realizado com sucesso!";
    }

    public String imprime(){
        return "-----------------------------------------------------\nNome do aluno: " + nome + "\nMatricula: " +
    matricula + "\nCurso: " + curso + "\nPeriodo: " + periodo + "\nDisciplinas Matriculadas: " + 
                disciplinasMatriculadas.toString() + "\n-----------------------------------------------------\n";
    }
```

Depois, fiz um método main chamado SistemaAcadêmico que deve servir para o usuário escolher uma opção e realizar a operação desejada.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SistemaAcademico {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aluno alunos[];

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Informe a quantidade de alunos que será cadastrada:");
        alunos = new Aluno[s.nextInt()];
        System.out.println("Digite o número da opção escolhida:");
        System.out.println("1 - Cadastrar aluno;");
        System.out.println("2 - Excluir aluno por nome;");
        System.out.println("3 - Listar alunos;");
        System.out.println("4 - Matricular aluno em disciplina;");
        System.out.println("5 - Cancelar disciplina;");
        System.out.println("6 - Imprimir lista de alunos e disciplinas matriculadas");


    }

}
```

Devo associar cada uma das opções com alguns métodos, mas eu travei no primeiro porque eu não entendi a assinatura que me foi pedida.

```
public static void cadastrarAluno(Aluno aluno){}
```

O objeto Aluno passado como parâmetro me deixou confuso, não sei como usá-lo. No meu entendimento, eu deveria ter um método sem parâmetros, instanciar um objeto `aluno` no início e pedir ao usuário através de *prints* na tela para informar o valor de cada atributo do meu objeto.

Não sei se deixei minha dúvida clara, mas como é o usuário que vai decidir executar o método, eu não sei como esse parâmetro vai ser passado.

Comment: A pergunta não está nada clara. A informação relevante sobre como é composto o `cadastrarAluno` não esta nela. Não está claro porque este método tem essa assinatura. Se não quer passar um parâmetro, não o faça. Talvez você não entenda o que é um parâmetro. Ela é uma variável local cuja inicialização ocorre no momento da chamada do método. Esta é a dúvida?

Comment: Eu estou estudando java e esse é um exercício que me foi passado. No enunciado me é pedido para implementar um método com essa assinatura. Mas se o método será chamado pelo usuário em tempo de execução, eu não sei como atribuir esse parâmetro. Sei resolver o problema sem o parâmetro, mas fiquei pensando que se foi solicitado dessa forma, deve haver uma maneira de fazer que eu não sei por conhecer pouco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O requisito do exercício parece fazer pouco ou nenhum sentido. Se o método deve cadastrar o aluno, ele deveria fazer o todo, não deveria exigir que passasse um objeto para ele. Eu preferia não usar essa assinatura e apenas retornar o objeto criado dentro deste método (se isso for necessário). Eu iria pelo caminho que está pensando e justificaria a decisão. Se o professor quer testar sua capacidade de inicializar o objeto fora do método, ele que faça um exercício mais bem escrito. Espero pelo menos que seja só mais um curso ruim de internet e nada oficial.

Se insistir nisso, pode criar um objeto vazio (em estado possivelmente inválido), ou criar com dados fictícios (o que eu acho bem pior).

Uma forma:

```
Aluno aluno = null;
cadastrarAluno(aluno);
```

Aí atende o requisito da assinatura. Dentro do método terá que criar o objeto no parâmetro recebido

Se quiser criar o objeto antes de chamar sem o método ser obrigado inicializar a variável (algo pior) pode fazê-lo:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
cadastrarAluno(aluno);
```

Mas nesse caso precisaria ter um construtor sem parâmetros na classe, o que não ocorre agora. Talvez tenha um requisito impedindo isso. Eu acho ruim que tenha esse construtor porque ele permite ter um objeto em estado inválido e teria até dificuldade em identificar que isso está ocorrendo. O `null` pelo menos deixa claro a invalidade do estado.

A última opção seria:

```
Aluno aluno = new Aluno(null, null, null, 0, 0);
cadastrarAluno(aluno);
```

Obviamente que o parâmetro do aluno no método já funciona como uma variável local declarada no método. Sua inicialização ocorrerá na chamada do método, então não precisa criar uma variável para manipular este objeto, esta variável já é o parâmetro.

Tente entender o que é a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) e o que é o valor. Ao contrário da crença popular entre iniciantes em programação, elas são coisas distintas. Uma passagem de argumento para um parâmetro é passar um valor, o parâmetro é a variável.

O operador `new` é usado para criar um objeto, ou seja, criar um valor por referência.

A assinatura melhor seria:

```
public static Aluno cadastrarAluno()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Instance.java).